# Open Source license that requires giving credit in user's web site

Tags: open-source, licensing

I have this small code library that I'm considering releasing into Open Source. I want to release it under something similar to MIT License, i.e. no significant restrictions, however I would like to require that if you use my library on your servers, you have to give me credit on your website.

Basically, I want a license which is to MIT License as AGPL is to GPL.

Does something like this exist, or do I have to write my own?

Or is this just a Really Bad Idea?

**EDIT**: I guess I should have left out the "write my own" part. I'm not a lawyer, and I don't want to pay one. I just thought it would be nice to be able to tell if someone's using my lib with a simple Google search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that CC is not so great for software :(

CPAL is good alternative, because it has better definition of "source code"
(which CC don't have)

it's based on Mozilla Public License, but it has Attribution .
License is approved by OSI in 2007.

http://opensource.org/licenses/cpal_1.0

and here is example of license that facebook uses for FBOpen Platform.

http://developers.facebook.com/fbopen/cpal.html

Comment: +1 if I had any votes left today :)

Answer (score 14):

Look here :

http://www.opensource.org/licenses/category

and pleeeeeeeeeeease don't write your own!

From Aaron Digulla comment (Thank you Aaron):

*It takes a lawyer a long time to write a license that will actually hold in court (and why would you want a license that doesn't?) Hundreds of people all over the world worked several MONTHS on GPL v3!  – Aaron Digulla*

On the other side :

When you work in a company and you will use opensource, you normally can choose
among the licenses that are "approved" in the company :-).

a new license is normally a  NO GO :-(

**ATTENTION** to Kodisha: From the cc-site:

*Creative Commons licenses should not be used for software. We strongly encourage you to use one of the very good software licenses which are already available.*

PS : [see What Open Source License to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236699/what-open-source-license-to-choose)

Comment: +1 for "use a existing license"

Comment: I suggest to explain why it's a no go: It takes a lawyer a long time to write a license that will actually hold in court (and why would you want a license that doesn't?) Hundreds of people all over the world worked several MONTHS on GPL v3!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  Creative Commons Attribution licence?

> This license lets others distribute,
>   remix, tweak, and build upon your
>   work, even commercially, as long as
>   they credit you for the original
>   creation. This is the most
>   accommodating of licenses offered, in
>   terms of what others can do with your
>   works licensed under Attribution.

http://creativecommons.org/about/licenses/

Comment: and you get to choose between commercial and non-commercial ones.. more details on the link above..

Comment: -1 for Creative Commons: They are *not* meant for software and there are nasty legal implications if you do!

Comment: I'd really love if there was a simple way to chose a license for an OSS project :( CC is so easy compared to all the rest ... *sigh* So my -1 is not meant to criticize but as a warning for all the people not to fall into this trap ... copyright law sux :((

Answer (score 0):

Please remember: there was a good reason why MIT and BSD *removed* the requirement for attribution from their licenses.

Comment: Why? Please explain.